# How to design database to store attributes of attributes into database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing database for jewellery website in which a lot of products will store. While designing tables for attributes of products i stuck. My problem is how store product attributes and there sub attributes and so on in database.

Up to now i have created 3 tables for product and attributes -

1. tbl_attribute

   ```
   Structure: attribute_id*, attribute_name
   ```
2. tbl_products

   ```
   Structure: product_id*, category_id(FK), product_name, seo, description, metatags, length, width, height, weight, image, status
   ```
3. tbl_products_attribute

   ```
   Structure: product_id(fk), attribute_id(fk), value
   ```

---

I have a situation suppose Necklace have 5 stones (Stone is attribute) and each stones have following sub attributes
1. Stone Name
2. Stone Color
3. Stone Treated Method
4. Stone Clearity
5. Stone Shape
6. Stone Price

and so on etc.... and i have **So many attributes like stone** so can you please help me how to design the table for these attributes.

Depends on that attributes i have to search(FILTER || Faceted Search) the products in front end.

Like: [www.firemountaingems.com](http://www.firemountaingems.com/Shop/Pendants?T=T1B)

---

Detailed attributes and sub attributes list:

```
Alphabatical
Availability (Sold Individualy, Sold in Bulk)
Birth Stone
Brands
Color (red, green, blue)
Design Type
Gender (Male, Female)
Images 
Karat (18k, 22k, 24k)
Link
Make (Hand, Machine, Oxidised)
Making Percent
Material Type (Leather, Gemstone, etc)
Metal Art
Metal Stamp
Metal Type (Gold, Silver, PLatinum etc)
Model
Name
Price
Purity
Shapes (round, oval, emerald, diamond etc)
Short Description
Sides (single, both,)
Size (small, big etc)
Special Price
Status
Stone (Name, Color, Treated Method, Clearity, Shape, Price, Main Stone Color (Red, Pink, Green))
Stringing Material
Warranty
Wastage Percent
Weight
Wire - Wrapping Wire
```

Up to now i have search so many tutorials and article on net as well as on stack overflow.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you cant afford creating tables like this the best approach is to have only 1 product table and 1 attributes table which will be having all attributes of a product but with columns attribute_level and parent_id where parent_id refers id of same table.

Example:
products table:

```
ID | Name
----------
1  | Necklace


ID | ParentID | AttributeName | ProductID | AttributeLevel | AttributeDescription
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |          | Stone         | 1         | 1              | stone description in general
2  | 1        | StoneName     | 1         | 2              | Ruby
```

In this way you can make hirerchy of attribute levels within one table.

Comment: Dear Immam i understand what you are trying to explain and this is very helpful in my case i like it, but again i have one query how i will search the products on the basis of the attributes and sub attributes. I have to filter the products on basis of so many attributes, like category, metal, shape, color, price etc.

Comment: @HappySingh i suggest to use 1 table for saving info of all levels of attributes (attributes,subattributes and so on) wihch will be having ID as primary key and then for its subattribute that id will be set in its parentID and it will work.

Comment: suppose if you have to search for products having black color.Now what problem are you seeing in its search query using my approach where each attribute has its productid and for link to all its parent attributes it has parentid and same for child attributes.

Comment: for stone1 you can store attributes in 1 column of type BIGText separated by '|' i.e Ruby|Red|square and you can query on this column using like operator now suppose you want to search red rubies but yes only for price you need to add a separate column because may be user will be interested to search stones<100$ and using 1 column approach will make it difficult but if you want to provide search exactly for some amount no less or greater than you can use that single column for price too.

Comment: Storing multiple values in a single column... Yucky. :(